# Не работает getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть JS-код который достаёт из урла Get-запрос (utm-метки) и вставляет данные в input, для последующей отправки в форму письма, если таковое будет. Если использовать getElementsById, то все прекрасно работает. Но дело в том, что форм на странице несколько, поэтому небоходимо использовать class, но getElementsByClassName не работает.

```
    window.onload = function(){

    var tmp = new Array();      // два вспомагательных
    var tmp2 = new Array();     // массива
    var param = new Array();
    var get = location.search;  // строка GET запроса
    if(get != '') { 
        tmp = (get.substr(1)).split('&');   // разделяем переменные
        for(var i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');       // массив param будет содержать
            param[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];       // пары ключ(имя переменной)->значение
        }
    var objsource = document.getElementsByClassName('source');  // вывод на экран 
    var objmedium = document.getElementsByClassName('medium');
    var objcampaign = document.getElementsByClassName('campaign');
    for (var key in param) {
        if (key == 'utm_source') {
        objsource.value += key+" = "+param[key]+"<br>";
        }
        if (key == 'utm_medium') {
        objmedium.innerHTML += key+" = "+param[key]+"<br>";
        }
        if (key == 'utm_campaign') {
        objmedium.innerHTML += key+" = "+param[key]+"<br>";
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Ну и, соответственно, три инпута:

```
 <input type="text" class="source" value="" /></div>
<input type="text" class="medium" value="" /></div>
<input type="text" class="campaign" value="" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` Возвращает набор элементов.

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не очень силен в JS, подскажите, как быть в данной ситуации?

Comment: @drm, по сути, вы получаете массив с найденными элементами, т.к. вполне вероятно, что в документе может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым классом. Можно поступить несколькими способами. Первый - это если заранее известно, что элемент всего один, то просто брать первый элемент:

    objsource[0].value = '...';

Или же если несколько элементов, то пройтись в цикле:

    for(var i=0; i < objsource.length; i++) {
        objsource[i].value = '...';
    }

Comment: Да, теперь понятно, спасибо большое.

Comment: @drm, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).